# Selecting the parent DIV when I only whan to select the children DIV

Tags: jquery, html

I have two divs, one inside of the other:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="children">
        Click me
    </div>
</div>
```

​

When I click the children div using jquery, the parent became clicked too.

```
$(function() {
   $("div").click(function(){
       alert("The id of the selected item is: " + $(this).attr("id"));
   });
});​
```

What can I do to avoid that? Here's my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gzpPB/1/

Comment: Why not just target the child div by its ID?

Comment: Hey, @GalloPinto, it might be nice if you could choose an answer to this question... thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most robust solution would be to simply give all click-accepting DIV elements a specific class. That way, no matter where, or how deep they are nested, only the element with the "button" class will be triggered.

NEW CODE:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="children" class="button">
        Click me
    </div>
</div>


$(function() {
   $(".button").click(function(){
       alert("The id of the selected item is: " + $(this).attr("id"));
   });
});​
```

If you are using jQuery 1.8 or higher, you will need to do it this way:

```
$(function() {
       $(document).on('click', ".button", function(){
           alert("The id of the selected item is: " + $(this).attr("id"));
       });
    });​
```

Answer (score 2):

Be more specific in your selector:

```
$("#children") instead of $("div")
```

Answer (score 0):

Becoz you are just targeting the div elements on the page .

Use `e.target` to target the specific div.
Also `e.stopPropagation()`

```
$(function() {
       $("div").click(function(e){
           if( e.target.id == 'children'){
               e.stopPropagation();
               alert("The id of the selected item is: " + $(this).attr("id"));
           }
        });
    });
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/v5CJr/)**

Answer (score 0):

Use `.stopPropagation()` like:

```
$(function() {
   $("div").click(function(e){
       e.stopPropagation();
       alert("The id of the selected item is: " + $(this).attr("id"));
   });
});​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/gzpPB/5/)**

Your code alerts for both divs when you click on the child div because of [bubbling](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#dom-event-architecture). The click on the child travels up to the parent and then triggers the laert again because your jQuery is targeting all divs, not specific divs. You could target *only* the child div only by using `$("#children")`. However, you can also stop the bubbling using `stopPropagation()` which would allow your alert to work when you click on any div, and not just a specific one.